# Add conditional value to excel using python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

My excel worksheet has 1 column in column E like this

E

19000

19100

19200
.
.
.
23000
I want to use python to add a symbol to the cell next to particular value , that is column F.
For example i want to add # next to 19200, that is:

E   |  F

19000 |

19100 |

19200 |  #
.
.
.

The python code below cannot find the desied value in column E:

```
ce=0
col=ws['E']

for cel in range(0, len(col), 1):
    print(ce)
    ce=+1
    print(cel)
    for cc in col:

        if (cc.value==19200):
            ws.cell(row=int(ce), column=(3)).value=#
            wb.save("data.xlsx")
            print(ce)
    ce=+1
print(ce)
```

Pease help, thank you.

Comment: That can't be your actual code.  The `#` is not in quotes, which would make it a comment and result in a syntax error.  And I don't understand what you're doing with the nested loop here.  Aren't they both iterating through column E?  And shouldn't `column=(3)` be `column=6`?

Comment: I have change the codes many times, i just find increment is not in line with the search, so i add a few print(ce) to see what have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want.

```
col=ws['E']

for cc in col:
    if cc.value==19200:
        ws.cell(row=cc.row, column=6).value='#'
wb.save("data.xlsx")
```